# Getting Memory usage of a tensorflow model with guppy.hpy() not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I am loading a saved model of tensorflow (`.pb` file) and trying to evaluate how much memory it allocates for the model with `guppy` package. Following a [simple tutorial](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/python/guppy-heapy-profile-memory-usage-in-python), here is what i tried:

```py
from guppy import hpy
import tensorflow as tf

heap = hpy()

print("Heap Status at starting: ")
heap_status1 = heap.heap()
print("Heap Size : ",  heap_status1.size, " bytes\n")
print(heap_status1)

heap.setref()

print("\nHeap Status after setting reference point: ")
heap_status2 = heap.heap()
print("Heap size: ", heap_status2.size, " bytes\n")
print(heap_status2)

model_path = "./saved_model/" #.pb file directory
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)

print("\nHeap status after creating model: ")
heap_status3 = heap.heap()
print("Heap size: ", heap_status3.size, " bytes\n")
print(heap_status3)

print("Memory used by the model: ", heap_status3.size - heap_status2.size)
```

I don't know why, but when i run the code it suddenly stops executing when i call `heap_status1 = heap.heap()`. It doesn't throw any error.

This same code runs fine when i don't use anything related to tensorflow, i.e. it runs successfully when i just create some random lists, strings, etc instead of loading a tensorflow model.

**Note**: my model will run in a **CPU device**. Unfortunately, `tf.config.experimental.get_memory_info` works with GPUs only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, the crash may be related to https://github.com/zhuyifei1999/guppy3/issues/25. Check pywin32 version and if it is < 300, upgrade pywin32 with

```
pip install -U pywin32
```